# How to make a link function change a scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS to make a model that responds to a click from the user. I have all the information for the model in the controller (other elements will be added to the scope later), and the directive handles showing the element in the view and performing actions on it, such as minimizing it on click.

What I'm having trouble with is making the link function in my makeDialog directive change the value of experimentDialog.minimized in the model. How can I accomplish this? What am I doing wrong?
Right now, nothing happens when you click the button -- so help troubleshooting is also appreciated.
Let me know if you need any more information!

Angular:

```
angular.module('root', [])
  .controller('index', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.experimentDialog = {
      minimized: false,
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      top: 10,
      left: 10,
      template: 'experiment-dialog.html'
    };
  }])

  .directive('makeDialog', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.minimize = function() {
            scope.model.minimized = true;
            scope.$apply();
          };
        }
    };
});
```

dialog.html:

```
<html>

<link href='dialog.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <body>
        <div class='dialog' ng-hide={{model.minimized}}>
                <button id='minimize' ng-click="minimize()"> _ </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: if it helps, here is the whole thing on Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3S9q53VfGqRrWbVgR5XU?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your button does change the model. The problem was your `ng-hide` syntax. I display the model in the box so you can see the values.

```
<div class='dialog' ... ng-hide="model.minimized"> <!-- no {{}}! -->
```

This [forked plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MUY8EI5DcBic3QJ1ubmb?p=preview) has, what I believe to be, your intended effect.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked! I'm new to angular -- if you have a chance, could you explain why the double curly braces weren't working?

Comment: The tl;dr is [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) is an angular directive that expects an expression, some snippet that can be evaluated, not an [interpolated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) value.